# When should I use dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore's _saveEverything function?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am using dojo 1.6 version. My understanding is: if store._saveEverything = saveCompleteCallback; is defined, then the callback function saveCompleteCallback  will be called **only** when store.save() is called?

And do I need to use the **1st** and **2nd params** defined in the callback function saveCompleteCallback(**saveSuccess**, **saveFail**, storeData){}? Cause I only know that I need to use them when calling store.save({onComplete: **saveSuccess**, onError: **saveFail**})?

Answer (score 0):

First I only use _saveEverything when I need a dojox.data.dataGrid's data to be xhrPosted and then xhrGeted.

Assume you define: store._saveEverything = saveCompleteCallback;

I just figured out, that including the 1st and 2nd params of saveCompleteCallback(saveSuccess, saveFail, storeData) are necessary, because an extra saveSuccess() and saveFail() function needs to be called again in saveCompleteCallback(). e.g.

```
// When you wanna upload datagrid, you click upload button
Store.save({ onComplete : saveSuccess, onError : saveFail });

// Definition of saveCompleteCallback
function saveCompleteCallback(saveSuccess, saveFail, storeData) {
  dojo.xhrpost(
    url: posturl,
    postData:storeData,
    load: function(data) {
      // saveSuccess() must be invoked here again, 
      // otherwise this function will not be called
      saveSuccess();
    }
  );
}

function saveSuccess() {
    dataGrid = dijit.byId('YOUR DATAGRID ID');
    dojo.xhrGet(
        url: geturl, 
        load: function(date){
            // The reason that a new xhrGet is called is db data is updated
            // So the dataGrid will have no value after xhrPost
            var store = new dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore({data: data});
            store._saveEverything = saveEverything;
            store.clearOnClose = true;
            store.urlPreventCache = true;
            dataGrid.setStore(store);
        }
    );
}
```